# Ignore duplicate records from table using SQL QUERY(no deletion)

Tags: sql

```
1         Banana           1$
1         watermelon       1$
1         Apple            1$
2         Banana           1$
3         Almond           1$
3         peanut           1$
4         Grapes           1$
```

I need below output

```
id        product        price

2         Banana           1$
4         Grapes           1$
```

Can anyone help me in writing query to get above result?

Comment: Your question is confusing. You wrote "ignore duplicate", but in example output you list only duplicates. What exactly you need?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Please also include examples of what you have already tried and any errors you are getting so that we can get you a complete and accurate response.

Comment: Sorry about that if i could not express myself in question. but i need output where ignore same records and select only unique one (2,4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this SQL:

```
select id, product, price
from table t1
where (select count(t2.id) from table t2 where t2.id = t1.id) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this query. You should format it taking into account the syntax of the DBMS you are using...

```
SELECT q AS id, product, price
FROM
(SELECT COUNT(id) AS q, product, price
FROM table
GROUP BY id)
WHERE q = 1
```

I assumed you meant duplicate ids. It's the only way you would need the output you referred in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT my_table.id, product, price
FROM my_table
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT id,
          count(product) AS p_count
   FROM my_table
   GROUP BY id) AS t ON t.id = my_table.id
WHERE t.p_count = 1
```

Comment: I am using this service first time how to upvote and accept it?

Comment: to upvote - click on the arrow up, to accept - click on the V.

Comment: Thank you. just want add something . ouput is correct but another extra column(id) and P_count is in result window, is any way to skip extra column.

Answer (score 0):

This is best done using `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.product <> t.product
                 );
```

This should be faster than other methods.  It would make particularly good use of an index on `(id, product)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sexy answer:

```
  select id, product, price
    from table t1
    inner join (select id 
         from table group by id 
         having count(*)=1) t2 
    on t2.id = t1.id
```